# Proof by contradiction how to show is properly

Tags: proof-writing

For every
$x \in \left[\pi/2,\pi\right]\,,\ \sin\left(x\right) − \cos\left(x\right) \geq 1$.

I have drawn the graph and can clearly see that A is true however how do I prove it correctly.

Comment: The function $\sin x-\cos x$ is obviously positive in our interval. Show that the **square** is $\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sin\pars{x} - \cos\pars{x}&
=\sin\pars{x} - \tan\pars{\pi/4}\cos\pars{x}
={\sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{\pi/4}  - \sin\pars{\pi/4}\cos\pars{x}\over \cos\pars{\pi/4}}
\\[5mm]&=\root{2}\sin\pars{x - {\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

> Also, with $\quad\ds{\xi\ \in\ \bracks{{\pi \over 4},{3\pi \over 4}}}$:
>   $$
> \sin\pars{\xi} \geq \sin\pars{\pi \over 4} = {1 \over \root{2}}
> $$

Then,
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sin\pars{x} - \cos\pars{x}} \geq \root{2}\,{1 \over \root{2}}
=\color{#66f}{\Large 1}\,,\qquad x\ \in\ \bracks{{\pi \over 2},\pi}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume the contrary. For simplicity, I have changed the region of x to an open interval.

That is, there exists an $x ∈ (π/2, π)$, such that $\sin x − \cos x \lt 1$.

[Please skip the following line and continue from its next.]

Then, try some values for x in that range to see the contradiction. An example is x = 3π/4.

---

Then, $\sin x \lt 1 + \cos x$

For x belongs to the given region, $0 \lt \sin x$.

∴ $0 \lt sin x \lt 1 + \cos x$

Squaring, we have $\sin ^2 x \lt 1 + 2\cos x + \cos ^2 x$

Simplifying, we have $0 \lt \cos x(\cos + 1)$

Then, $0 \lt \cos x(\cos + 1) = (negative)(positive)$; for x lying in the given region

i.e. , $0 \lt \cos x(\cos + 1) \lt 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: how do you prove it by contradiction?

Comment: @Tk706 I have edited my answer with extra details. Hope that can clear the matter.